# PHP: show messages from form validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

Hi I've got a simple form and a validation function.
When I submit the form empty no error messages are showing up. What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe a better solution to output error messages of a form validation?

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
?>

<html>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username">
<br />
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<span><?php echo $nameErr ?></span>
<span><?php echo $pwErr ?></span>

</html>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    validateForm();
}

?>
```

here is the functions.php file:

```
<?php

function validateForm()
{
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) 
    {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $pwErr = "Password is required";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe you have to `echo` your errors to display them.

Comment: Yes, use client side validation (javascript) and server side validation (PHP).

Comment: @VincentDecaux What do you mean? I already set an echo before the variable.

Comment: Oh dear didn't see, you have to learn about closures. Your variables can't be used outside your function.

Comment: Offtopic but `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` doesn't do a thing, you'll need to `echo` it.

Comment: Take a look at [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

Functions.php

```
<?php

    function validateForm()
    {
        $errors = array();

        if (empty($_POST["username"])) 
        {
            $errors[] = "Name is required";
        }

        if (empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $errors[] = "Password is required";
        }

        return '<span>'.implode('</span>,<span>', $errors).'</span>';
    }

    ?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
?>

<html>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username">
<br />
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>


<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo validateForm();    
}
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `$msg` variable out of the function, and above everything, before instantiate it. And i used a *global* method to call it inside the function, and now we got access to this variable scope inside the function we created.

Your new include or require *functions.php* file should look like this:

```
<?php
$msg = "";
function validateForm($name, $pwd){
    global $msg;    
    if(isset($_POST[$name]) && empty($_POST[$name])){
        $msg .= "Wrong name passed\n";  
    } elseif(isset($_POST[$pwd]) && empty($_POST[$pwd])){
        $msg .= "Wrong password\n"; 
    } else {
        $msg .= "Logged\n"; 
    }   
}
?>
```

The *html* content and the include part:

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';
if(isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
    validateForm('username','password');
}
?>
<html>
<form action="" method="POST">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username">
<br />
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<span><?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : NULL; ?></span>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make variables `$nameErr` and `$pwErr` inside `validateForm()` global since you want to `echo` those variables outside the function. Variables inside a function doesn't have global scope. It works only inside function. Make your variables global like this:

```
<?php

function validateForm(){
if (empty($_POST["username"])) 
{

   $nameEr = "Name is required";
   $GLOBALS['nameErr']=$nameEr;
}

if (empty($_POST['password']))
{

   $pwEr = "Password is required";
   $GLOBALS['pwErr']=$pwEr;
}
}

?>
```

and also echo

```
 <span><?php echo $nameErr ?></span>
 <span><?php echo $pwErr ?></span>
```

after running `validateForm()` function.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the function AFTER you show the error messages.
Try calling it right after the declaration, before the echos.

I've also read Vincent comment, its true, you either have to declare the vars as global, or think of something else

Comment: You're Right Daan i overlooked that. I've edited my answer now.

Answer (score -1):

Something I think better :

```
function validateForm()
{
    var $errors = array();

    if (empty($_POST["username"])) 
    {
        $errors[] = "Name is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $errors[] = "Password is required";
    }

    return '<span>'.implode('</span>,<span>', $errors).'</span>';
}
```

Then use in your view where to want to show errors :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo validateForm();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
include "functions.php";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    validateForm();
}

?>
```

You got to call the function before assembling your html

Answer (score -2):

If you want this script to work, validation code need to be at begining of the script.

functions.php

```
function validateForm(&$nameErr, &$pwErr)
{
    if (empty($_POST["username"])) 
    {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $pwErr = "Password is required";
    }
}
```

html

```
    include "functions.php";


$nameErr = "";
$pwErr = "";
if (isset($_POST["username"]))
{
    validateForm($nameErr, $pwErr);
}

?>

<html>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username">
<br />
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

<span><?php echo $nameErr ?></span>
<span><?php echo $pwErr ?></span>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a comment, and a wrong one. Don't post as an answer please.

Comment: No, as we have said in comments, the variable in function are not accessible from the code outside the function. You can place your function at top, or bottom, it won't work.

Comment: look at my edited answer, I have tested this and works.

Comment: Woaw ... don't use global please. This is bad !

Comment: Yes this is bad, but I think you just want to this working example, now I edited and tested without globals.

Comment: My solution works and I have 2 minuses wooooooooooooow wtf is with stackoverflow ????!!!???!?!?!??